# C# TimeZone info lost when assigning DateTime to DataRow

Tags: c#, timezone, datarow

As the title says after I assign a DateTime object with time zone UTC it loses its TimeZone info when assigned to a DataRow.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     DateTime universalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
     DataRow row = table.NewRow();

     row["Time"] = universalTime;

     /* writes Kind: Utc */
     Console.WriteLine("Universal time      : " + universalTime + ", kind: " + universalTime.Kind);

     /* writes Kind: Unspecified */
     Console.WriteLine("Same time in DataRow: " + row["Time"] + ", kind: " + ((DateTime)row["Time"]).Kind);

     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

After assigning to DataRow it says Kind = Unspecified.

Is this a bug in the DataRow or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems its already answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990809/how-to-persist-datetime-kind-while-storing-a-datetime-object-into-a-data-table]

Comment: Does it matter? For storing times in databases, storing as UTC is the only format that makes sense anyway.

Comment: The dup post has the answer, but also be aware that the `Kind` doesn't really persist time zone information.  It's just a rule that says how the value should be treated when interacting with time zone functions.  And it is typically not persisted when saving in data anyway.  You can think of `UTC` as a time zone, but `Local` or `Unspecified` kinds are a bit different.  If persistence is what you are after, you might want to look at `DateTimeOffset`.  Even if your offset is zero, it will at least be persisted that way and not lost.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because there is no time-zone information available in your persistence layer's `datetime` data type.

For example, on SQL Server, the `datetime` type has no time-zone information. So, any C# value of type `DateTime` has only its value stored. This is similar to how Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework work.

My work-around has usually been to decide on a time zone (UTC) for all persisted `DateTime` values and do conversions before persistence and after retrieval.

Something like this:

```
public DateTime InputTime(DateTime time) {
    if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Time values cannot be input to the data store with unspecified kind.");
    }
    return time.ToUniversalTime();
}

public DateTime OutputTime(DateTime time) {
    if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
        time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
    return time.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure these make sense.  For `InputTime`, usually dates coming from input are `Unspecified` because they are parsed from strings in the UI.  For `OutputTime`, it certainly doesn't make sense because you are marking the time as UTC but then trying to convert it to UTC again, which would be a no-op.  I'm not certain how either of these would help the OP's issue.  But thanks for trying.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Dates from UI should be converted to `DateTimeKind.Local` far in advance of the persistence layer. That's why the `InputTime` throws an exception: dates need to have a known `Kind` before persisting. The `OutputTime` method is meant to take dates directly from the persistence layer which have, in nearly all cases (but maybe not in unit-test scenarios), an unspecified `Kind`. it applies the UTC kind and returns that value in UTC (which is also the returned kind if the `time` parameter happens to have a specified `Kind`.

Comment: Not trying to start an argument, but I have to disagree with you.  In almost all cases, `DateTimeKind.Local` is evil.  Read [my blog post on the subject](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/), and if you don't believe me - see [what Jon Skeet thought about this](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).  It has a minor convenience in *pure desktop* apps, but other than that it just gets in the way and makes a mess of things.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Yes, this example comes from a desktop application. User-entered dates are given the `Local` kind and immediately converted to UTC before any processing. I never compare dates or do any other processing before calling `ToUniversalTime`, and the example I gave demonstrates how I can guarantee all persisted dates have a valid `Kind`. In practice, this isn't much different from calling `DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime`, but I agree that passing around instances of `DateTimeOffset` is probably safer than `DateTime`, and maybe that's something I need to look into further.

Comment: Sure, I can understand that.  But there is still a bug in that `ToUniversalTime` doesn't do anything if the kind is already UTC, and `SpecifyKind` doesn't do any conversions.  So your `OutputTime` function only does anything if the `time` parameter is of `Local` kind.

Comment: @MattJohnson - In your blog, you call for marking `DateTimeKind.Local as [Obsolete]`. How do you suggest we handle dates that come from UI without time-zone information? Many WPF controls and plugins bind `DateTime` values with an unspecified kind. Is there something in `DateTimeOffset` like `ParseFromLocal(string input)`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33378/discussion-between-matt-johnson-and-ken)