# How to set C# DataTable Locale to be UTC

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I create a datatable, and then convert it to a Xml string to send across a network.

The DataTable is created in the US BUT with UTC times in a DateTime column.

When I received it in UK, the timezone appears to be US!

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        table.TableName = ZeroMQTopic;
        table.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        string tableXML = sw.ToString();
```

This is the XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Test" msdata:Locale="en-US">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Test" msdata:Locale="en-US">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="utcDT" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Symbol" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Close" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Test>

    <utcDT>2019-11-19T16:08:00-05:00</utcDT>    <<<<<<<<< HERE IS THE ISSUE

    <Symbol>Widget</Symbol>
    <Close>31.25</Close>
  </Test>
</NewDataSet>
```

I think I can set locale to be "en" BUT does that imply UTC or BST?

Or, is there some other way to force this to be UTC?

> EDIT 1

table is a subset from a larger table where I have set DateTimeMode to DataSetTimeMode.utc

```
var table = fullTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => AllowedSymbols.Contains(x.Field<string>("Symbol"))).CopyToDataTable();
```

BUT the DateTimeMode is NOT copied!

Also, I cannot set DateTimeMode on table afterwards - as it already has data!

Comment: Try setting the [`DataColumn.DateTimeMode` to `DataSetDateTime.Utc` as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3990942/215552).

Comment: Hmmm, that made no difference. Could it be to do with the locale?

Comment: Unlikely. The locale shouldn't change how the datetime value is stored, just how it is displayed.

Comment: No need to force to UTC.  You have the time zone specified "-05:00".  Any code that reads the date will automatically do the conversion.  So your EST time will be converted to local time when the file is read.

Comment: @ManInMoon - setting `table.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;` seems to generate the correct output: `utcDT>2019-11-19T21:08:00Z</utcDT>`.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zNuI2N.  If I don't set the `DateTimeMode` I get the wrong output, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/RyXCnH.  This looks like a duplicate of [How to persist DateTime Kind while storing a datetime object into a data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3990942/3744182) which was linked to above.

Comment: Incidentally, after setting `DateTimeMode ` the schema for `"utcDT"` changes as follows: `<xs:element name="utcDT" msdata:DateTimeMode="Utc" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />`.  Note the addition of the `msdata:DateTimeMode` attribute.

Comment: Ah I found issue. I can only change DateTimeMode when table is empty, which I do. Then I create a subset (see EDIT 1 above) with CopyToDataTable(). This does NOT copy DateTimeMode! and because it already has data - I can't set it afterwards... What can I do?

Comment: @dbc Please see EDIT 1

Comment: Then please see [How can I copy DateTimeMode in C# with CopyToDataTable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58953325/3744182).  Oh wait, that's your question.  Is there anything here to answer?  I almost went and started to answer this myself.