# How can I copy DateTimeMode in C# with CopyToDataTable()?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using CopyToDataTable to select a subset of a bigger table. However, the DateTimeMode of "utcDT" is not copied to new table:

```
        var x = new DataTable();
        x.Columns.Add("utcDT", typeof(System.DateTime));
        x.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;
        x.Columns.Add("Symbol", typeof(System.String));

        var newRow = x.NewRow();
        newRow.SetField("utcDT", DateTime.Now);
        newRow.SetField("Symbol","A");
        x.Rows.Add(newRow);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode.ToString());

        var y = x.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol")=="A").CopyToDataTable();
        Console.WriteLine(y.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode.ToString());
```

How can I ensure it is?

Comment: Add following to table y : y.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;

Comment: You can't because after there is data in y - you cannot change DateTimeMode!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's happening

`CopyToDataTable` only copies the columns' names and types.

[Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataTableExtensions.cs,159):

> ```
> // We do not copy the same properties that DataView.ToTable does.
> // If user needs that functionality, use other CopyToDataTable overloads.
> // The reasoning being, the IEnumerator<DataRow> can be sourced from
> // different DataTable, so we just use the "Default" instead of resolving the difference.
>
> foreach (DataColumn column in current.Table.Columns)
> {
>     table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
> }
> ```

## Solutions

## 1. `AsDataView().ToTable()`

Use `AsDataView` (see [Filtering with DataView (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/filtering-with-dataview-linq-to-dataset) and `ToTable()`:

```
var z = x.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol") == "A")
         .AsDataView()
         .ToTable();
```

### 2. `Clone()` -> `CopyToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T>, DataTable, LoadOption)`

You can use [Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=netframework-4.8) which '*Clones the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas and constraints.*' followed by `CopyToDataTable`, but the one version that takes the target table.

```
var z = x.Clone();
x.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol") == "A")
   .CopyToDataTable(z,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

## Test

```
(your dt definition here) 
Console.WriteLine(x.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode);

var y = x.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol") == "A")
        .CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
Console.WriteLine(y.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode);

var z = x.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol") == "A")
        .AsDataView()
        .ToTable();
Console.WriteLine(z.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode);

var a = x.Clone();
x.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(s => s.Field<string>("Symbol") == "A")
        .CopyToDataTable(a,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
Console.WriteLine(a.Columns["utcDT"].DateTimeMode);
```

### Output

```
Utc
UnspecifiedLocal
Utc
Utc
```

Comment: Wow. Number 1 is so simple! Thank you.

Comment: Do you know a way to specify the DataTimeMode of a column after it has been added to a table, but before any actual DateTimes have been added to it?

Comment: Is there a way to copy relations to?